# NullPointerException on Simple HttpPost

Tags: android, http-post, httprequest, getjson, httpexception

If username & Password are correct it has to show "SUCCESS" else it has to show "FAILED".I'm connecting to a server using `BasicNameValuePair`. and its showing `NullPointerException` on this line `int code = pres.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`

```
public class MyPostActivity extends Activity {
    DefaultHttpClient client;
    HttpPost post;
    HttpResponse res;
    HttpEntity ent;
    Button b;
    List<NameValuePair> pairs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        post = new HttpPost(
                "http://somesite.com/abc");
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "avinash"));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "avinash2"));

                try {
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                HttpResponse pres = null;
                try {
                    pres = client.execute(post);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int code = pres.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (code == 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Put web services file also

Comment: please share the logcat... check if you are getting any excepting in call to `execute`

Comment: Your web services code

Comment: Do you have the internet permission?

Comment: Have you added internet permission to your manifest file?

Comment: @NiravRanpara I don't have. I'm accessing college server

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar logcat added in post.

Comment: @AmeerMoaaviah Yes already done.

Comment: show us your manifest file.. you need to add internet permission in manifest to access internet from your application.. also you should not make network call on UI thread use `AsyncTask`

Comment: If response code is 401, then is some you will get IllegalStateException. Can you try putting pres.getStatusLine() under try/catch block and see which exception it throws. If it throws IllegalStateException, then server returns 401 error

Comment: please post the full logcat...

Comment: It is all about you are performing NetworkOperation on UI Thread. as @blackbelt post in his answer.

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar manifest http://pastebin.com/VUnG1PEr

Comment: There is problem is in web services

Answer (score 4):

You should add the internet permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Also you should not perform blocking operations on the `UI Thread`. In fact the `Http execute` will cause the `UI Thread` to hang waiting for a response from the server. This will cause `ANR` (application not responding). I suggest you to read the following [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please add this permission also to your manifest and try

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
```

And AsyncTask code

```
private class SignInService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            progressDilaog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Loading", true, false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "abc"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "bcd"));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            try {
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

              int responsecode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDilaog.dismiss();


    }
}
```

Comment: no error so far... and Its not showing the toast.. `int responsecode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
     if (responsecode == 200) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }`

Comment: You cannot use use Toast in doInBackground. Use a Log.d() if you want to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try {
            pres = client.execute(post);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int code = pres.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Well the null pointer exception happens because you probably get an exception in your `client.execute` line and do noting about it (you just catch it). That's why `pres` is null. You should print the exception to find your real problem.

Comment: how to print the exception??